# Undefined state in parent when setting state in child - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, react-state-management

I am trying to disable a button onClick based on if the button is the "current player". I am able to successfully get the correct code in the console log from my `PlayerButton` component, but I also get errors from my `App.js` that `.map is not a function`, meaning that my `playerData` (which works on initial mount) becomes undefined somehow after the onClick (i also receive `undefined` when trying to log `playerData` in `App.js` after the onClick).

Any ideas as to why my `setPlayerData` function isn't passing the data back to the parent component? I am thinking I may need to either use async await or useEffect somewhere, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this case.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './app.css'
import PlayerButton from './components/PlayerButton';

function App() {
  const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState([
    {
      name: "Player 1",
      currentPlayer: true,
      position: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Player 2",
      currentPlayer: false,
      position: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Player 3",
      currentPlayer: false,
      position: 0
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {playerData.map((player, index) => (
        <div key={player.name}>
          <PlayerButton player={player} index={index} setPlayerData={setPlayerData} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PlayerButton.js

```
import React from 'react';

const PlayerButton = ({ player: { name, currentPlayer }, index, setPlayerData }) => {

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setPlayerData(playerData => {
      playerData.map(player => {
        if (player.name === name) {
          console.log({ ...player, currentPlayer: false })
          return { ...player, currentPlayer: false }
        }
        return player
      })
    })
  }

  return (
    <button disabled={!currentPlayer} type="button" id={index + 1} className={`player${index + 1}-btn`} onClick={handleButtonClick}>{name}</button>
  )
}

export default PlayerButton;
```

I experimented with useEffect and async await because, I'm assuming, on update the parent component is trying to re-render before the data is successfully passed from the child. But if that were the case, wouldn't it just re-render the previous data?

Somehow, I'm not successfully updating the state in the child so the parent can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You've lost a return statement and returned `undefined` instead

Should be:

```
setPlayerData(playerData => {
  return playerData.map(player => {
    if (player.name === name) {
      console.log({ ...player, currentPlayer: false })
      return { ...player, currentPlayer: false }
    }
    return player
  })
})
```

Comment: That made sense, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. However, I found a solution and will add answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution. I created a function in the parent component that uses the `setPlayerData` function inside a callback `setCurrentPlayer`, passed it to the child, and executed the callback inside the child.

App.js

```
  const setCurrentPlayer = () => {
    setPlayerData((playerData.map((player) => {
      if (player.currentPlayer) {
        return { ...player, currentPlayer: false}
      }
      return player
    })))
  }
```

PlayerButton.js

```
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setCurrentPlayer();
  }
```

Comment: There should be absolutely no different between your solution and mine